# WPF - Setting the ComboBox Item Index and Item Value via LINQ Anonymous Types

Tags: wpf, linq, combobox, anonymous-types

I want to retrieve data from 2 columns of my database table and bind those 2 columns to the combobox item index and item value properties respectively. I retrieve my data from the samples table of my database with this anonymous query:

```
var result = from obj in context.Samples
             select new { obj.ID , obj.Name };
```

I want to set the default index value of each item in my combobox to `obj.ID` and the value of each respective combobox item to `obj.Name` so that rather than the items in my combo box having default values starting from 0, 1, 2.... their index values will have the value of `obj.ID` returned by my LINQ query and the actual value of the item will be `obj.Name`.

Sorry if this is a silly/amateurish question but I've spent a few hours trying to fix it and had no luck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectedIndex` property always goes from `-1` (no item is selected) to `count-1`, you can't change that. If you want to store the `ID` and `Name` for each item in the `ComboBox`, you can do that:

Create non-anonymous type `Sample` that contains those two properties. Then assign (or bind) collection of `Sample`s to the `ComboBox`'s `ItemSource` and set `DisplayMemberPath` to`Name`. Then you can access the `ID` of the selected item using `((Sample)yourComboBox.SelectedItem).ID`.